# Limit tablelayout rows, android

Tags: android, android-layout, rows, android-tablelayout

I was wondering if it's possible to add a limit such as maximum of row/s to the  tablelayout?

So I can, let's say, insert or show only last 100 instead of entire view. The data is dynamically populated and inserted.

**Solution**

```
    int _tableCount = _tableLayout.getChildCount();
    if(_tableCount > 100)
    {
        _tableLayout.removeViewAt(100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check count of rows by `getChildCount()` method, and add rows only if count is less than 100.